# How do you take $\lim_{j\to 1} \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-j^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2-2jxy+y^2}{2(1-j^2)}}$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

What is the limit:

$$\lim_{j\to 1}  \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-j^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2-2jxy+y^2}{2(1-j^2)}}$$

If I graph the function $p(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{1-j^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2-2jxy+y^2}{2(1-j^2)}}$ for values of j=.9, j=.99, and j=.999 I can see the 3-d plot gathers around the equation y=x.  So it seems like the limit exists, but how do I prove the limit exists analytically?

Answer (score 2):

Let $p_j(x, y)$ denote the function in question. Then $p_j(x, y)$ converges pointwise to $0$ outside the diagonal $y = x$ and diverges along $y = x$. But the pointwise limit is probably not what you want to consider here. So let us look at the distributional limit.

Notice that $p_j$ is the density of the multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma_j)$ where the covariance matrix is given by

$$ \Sigma_j = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & j \\ j & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Thus this distribution converges weakly to the (degenerate) multivariate normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0, \Sigma_1)$ as $j \to 1$. The resulting covariance matrix $\Sigma_1$ has two eigenvalues $2$ and $0$ with eigenvectors $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1, 1)$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1, 1)$, respectively. That is, this is essentially the $1$-dimensional normal distribution with variance $2$ along the diagonal $y = x$. Therefore $p_j(x, y)$ converges in distribution to

$$ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-\frac{(x+y)^2}{8}} \delta(x-y). $$

More directly, we may write

$$ p_j(x, y)
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1+j)}} e^{-\frac{(x+y)^2}{4(1+j)}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1-j)}} e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{4(1-j)}} $$

to see how the density concentrates along $y = x$ while keeping the bell-shape on $y = x$.

Answer (score 0):

One uses the fact that the Dirac delta distribution may be represented as a limit of a Gaussian with width going to zero:
$$\delta(x-y) = \lim_{\sigma\to 0^+} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}e^{\frac{(x-y)^2}{2\sigma^2}}. \tag{1} $$
At the level of a physicist's intuition for the delta function, the relation makes sense because for any finite width the Gaussian is normalised (will integrate to one) and furthermore highly peaked at $x-y$ in the limit $\sigma\to0$.

**Claim**: $$ L = \lim_{t\to1} \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1-t^2)}} e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2+xyt}{2(1-t^2)}}}_{f(x,y;t)} = \delta(x-y) \tag{2}$$

**Proof**: If the limit exists (in a distributional case), then by continuity of the exponential, it will be equal to the limit of expression where the $xyt$ term is replaced by $xy$. Therefore
 $$ L= \lim_{t \to 1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1-t^2)}} e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2(1-t^2)}} $$ 
Letting $\sigma = \sqrt{1-t^2}$ and using (1), we are done.

The precise expression you gave is $L/\sqrt{2\pi}=\delta(x-y)$. Note that the function occurs in the important ["Mehler's formula"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehler_kernel#Mehler.27s_formula) for Hermite polynomials.

Comment: Are you using $\delta$ here to both be the Dirac delta function *and* an arbitrary number tending to $1$?

Comment: A downvote just for that? Changed notation.

Comment: Down vote had nothing to do with me!